# I'm trying to make an auto-updating .bat program

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So, how I have it done right now, is that it that it calls another bat file to update it, and then that batch file updates, and sets %ERRORLEVEL% to 1. At the start of the original program, it checks if errorlevel is 1, if yes, it goes to the main menu, but right now, it doesn't call the update file, it just goes to the menu. This is my code

Main program

```
IF %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto begin
call updater.bat

:begin
echo MENU
```

Updater

```
set=errorlevel 1
wget (updatelink here)
call mainprogram.bat
```

Right now, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, which leads me to believe that some command is somehow increasing the errorlevel, but the only code before the errorlevel check is

```
@echo off
color 0f
cls
set currentver=v0.5.6
(check code)IF %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto begin
```

https://code.google.com/p/flashcart-helper/source/browse/trunk/0.6/FlashcartHelperRobocopy.bat
Here is what I have right now.

Comment: can you paste a working example please?

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of what it is you're trying to accomplish? (You're misusing ERRORLEVEL in your snippets above; You don't SET ERRORLEVEL directly. ERRORLEVEL is intended to reflect the success or failure of programs in your batch file. For example, if your "wget" were to fail, it would set the ERRORLEVEL, which you could then test using something like IF ERRORLEVEL 1 _do something_.)

Comment: It seems like you're not giving the whole picture... we need more code... because this looks highly incomplete. Why set currentver? It's not used elsewhere in this code. Why manually change the environment variable %errorlevel%? Not good to do.

Answer (score 4):

Don't play around with errorlevel. It's an internal variable. At the start of a batch, errorlevel will be 0 because all you've done is set a local variable. This will almost always ( never say never ) succeed. Also, if errorlevel is 1, and I'm reading this correctly you also seem to have an infinite loop? From what I understand of what you've said your batches are like this:

**Main**

```
@echo off
color 0f
cls
set currentver=v0.5.6
IF %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto begin
call updater.bat

:begin
echo MENU
```

**Updater**

```
set=errorlevel 1
wget (updatelink here)
call mainprogram.bat
```

As errorlevel get's overwritten each time you do anything you're asking for trouble. Change `%errorlevel%` to `%error%` and it should solve your problems. As it's a local environment variable it should also be passed between batch files. Just be careful not to use error elsewhere.

Comment: +1: agreed about manually changing %errorlevel% inside batch scripts. It's just bad practice because many commands echo an %errorlevel% after processing. So it's possible that a command could be changing that variable without the user ever knowing.

Comment: I tried that, that meant I had to set error at the beginning of the file, so when the updater calls back, it gets changed back, and just goes into a loop.

This is the source of my code with the auto-update code still in it.
https://code.google.com/p/flashcart-helper/source/browse/trunk/0.6/FlashcartHelperRobocopy.bat

Comment: I can't view that link; but if you set %error% or whatever you decide to call it at the top of your main batch it's going to 0 it's going to go into the updater every time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using Dropbox Public Folders and no wget. It uses PowerShell that in on Win7+ machines.
Update the below https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12345678/ url with your own.

It auto creates a .conf file for configuration.
Set __deploy_mode to 1 for the file on dropbox so the version file can be updated but the script not accidentally executed.

```
  @ECHO OFF
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

  SET time_start=%time%
  SET time_choice_wait=20
  SET script_ver=1.00
  SET script_name=%~n0
  SET server_url=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12345678/

  SET script_name_bat=%~dp0%script_name%.bat
  SET script_name_cfg=%~dp0%script_name%.conf
  SET script_name_latest_ver=%~dp0%script_name%.latest.ver

  ECHO %script_name% v%script_ver%
  ECHO %script_ver% > %script_name%.current.ver

  IF NOT EXIST "%script_name_cfg%" CALL :SCRIPT_MISSING_CFG
  FOR /f "delims=" %%x IN (%script_name%.conf) DO (SET "%%x")
  IF %__deploy_mode% EQU 1 GOTO :EOF
  IF %auto_update_compare% EQU 1 CALL :SCRIPT_COMPARE_VER




  :SCRIPT_MAIN
  REM =======================================
  REM ===       EDIT BELOW THIS LINE       ==

  REM TODO Add main content
  ECHO.
  ECHO Waiting for content...

  REM ===       EDIT ABOVE THIS LINE       ==
  REM =======================================
  GOTO END




  :SCRIPT_MISSING_CFG
  ECHO Creating new %script_name%.conf file...
  ECHO __deploy_mode=0                   > "%script_name_cfg%"
  ECHO repository_base_url=%server_url% >> "%script_name_cfg%"
  ECHO auto_update_compare=1                >> "%script_name_cfg%"
  ECHO auto_update_download=1               >> "%script_name_cfg%"
  ECHO Update %script_name%.conf as needed, then save and close to continue.
  ECHO Waiting for notepad to close...
  NOTEPAD "%script_name_cfg%"
  GOTO :EOF




  :SCRIPT_COMPARE_VER
  ECHO Please wait while script versions are compared...
  Powershell -command "& { (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%server_url%%script_name%.current.ver', '%script_name_latest_ver%') }"
  IF NOT EXIST "%script_name_latest_ver%" GOTO END
  SET /p script_latest_ver= < "%script_name_latest_ver%"
  IF %script_ver% EQU %script_latest_ver% CALL :SCRIPT_COMPARE_VER_SAME
  IF %script_ver% NEQ %script_latest_ver% CALL :SCRIPT_COMPARE_VER_DIFF
  GOTO :EOF

  :SCRIPT_COMPARE_VER_SAME
  ECHO Versions are both %script_name% v%script_ver%
  GOTO :EOF

  :SCRIPT_COMPARE_VER_DIFF
  ECHO Current Version:%script_ver% ^| Server Version:%script_latest_ver%
  IF %auto_update_download% EQU 1 GOTO SCRIPT_DOWNLOAD_SCRIPT
  ECHO.
  ECHO Would you like to download the latest %script_name% v%script_latest_ver%?
  ECHO Defaulting to N in %time_choice_wait% seconds...
  CHOICE /C YN /T %time_choice_wait% /D N
  IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO SCRIPT_DOWNLOAD_NOTHING
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO SCRIPT_DOWNLOAD_SCRIPT
  IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO SCRIPT_DOWNLOAD_NOTHING

  :SCRIPT_DOWNLOAD_SCRIPT
  ECHO Please wait while script downloads...
  Powershell -command "& { (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%server_url%%script_name%.bat', '%script_name_bat%') }"
  ECHO Script Updated to v%script_latest_ver%^^!
  REM User must exit script. Current batch is stale.
  GOTO :END

  :SCRIPT_DOWNLOAD_NOTHING
  GOTO :EOF



  :END
  SET time_end=%time%
  ECHO.
  ECHO Script started:%time_start%
  ECHO Script ended  :%time_end%
  :END_AGAIN
  pause
  ECHO.
  ECHO Please close this window
  ECHO.
  GOTO END_AGAIN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that through these steps：

1.put two files in server,a config file, a higher version bat file which need to update; set last version num. in config file.
2.client bat should be checked update at every startup time. you can read the news version in server config file, then compared to local bat file version. if not equal, so do update, else other wise.

Do you have any problems?